# Conservation of momentum, particles moving opposite to each other

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws

My friend came up with a situation that seemingly violates conservation of momentum. It involves two particles moving away from each other and a box. One particle has momentum $p$ and the other, because its moving in the opposite direction, $-p$. At some point, the $-p$ particle hits the box and bounces off elastically. Now it has p momentum. Before, the combined momentum was $(-p) + (p) = 0$. After, it is $(p) + (p) = 2p$. Doesn't this violate momentum conservation?

Comment: What's the momentum of the box now?

Comment: @probably_someone the box is large enough that it does not move. the momentum is unchanged. Think of it as a wall (in fact, I'll edit the post). Thanks!

Comment: There is no finite mass large enough that the box does not move.

Comment: @probably_someone oh my lord you're right. I didn't even realize that. So does the box somehow contribute 2p worth of momentum to the accelerating particle?

Comment: Since $p = mv$, the box does have enough momentum to make it work out, since its $m$ is so big. This is also, e.g. why it's possible to _walk_ at all, you take some momentum from the Earth.

Comment: so when I do a pushup I really do push the world down....haha! thanks so much for the explanation. if you put it as an answer I'll happily give you dat sweet rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is neglecting the momentum of the box. When the particle hits the box, it transfers a momentum $-2p$ to the box, so the box starts to move. If the box has mass $M$, then its velocity after the collision is $\frac{-2p}{M}$. If $M$ is very large, the box barely moves, but its large mass compensates in such a way that it has momentum exactly $-2p$.